# Laravel : Error in creating a relation to get first child of each parent entity

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to **eager load** first `child` entity of each `parent` entity like below :

```
$list = Parent::with('FirstChild')->get();
```

and the relation defined in `Parent` model is :

```
public function FirstChild()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Child')->first();
}
```

but this throws an error :

```
BadMethodCallException thrown with message "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()"
```

point is that when I remove `first()` method ,then it works!

Comment: in FirstChild() you are declaring relationship with Child. so first() does not work there. correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasMany()` is to declare relationship with models(itself or others). Here you ve declared relation with "Child" so when you remove `first()` it works.

So this should work fine

```
$list = Parent::with('FirstChild')->first();
```

Edit 
   can use hasOne() for first child and hasMany for ohter

```
public function FirstChild()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Child');
}
public function AllChild(){
   return $this->hasMany('Child');
}
```

Comment: your query affects returned records of Parent table ( returns just first one). I want list of parents along with first child of each.

Comment: then using hasOne() in FirstChild method would solve and for other make another mathod with hasMany()

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped. please just update your answer.